# UnityEngine.UI is not part of my project even though Unity UI is installed. How else can I change text at runtime?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, text

I want to change some text at runtime, but because UnityEngine.UI is somehow not part of my project, I can't access the Text component. I have already tried uninstalling and reinstalling Unity UI via the Package Manager.

I'm using Visual Studio Community 2019[16.10.0], and can clearly see that UnityEngine.UI is in the solution explorer. I'm using Unity 2020.3.19f1.

Can anyone help me to get it working or to find another way to change text?
[image: Here is a screenshot]

Comment: From [What are tags, and how should I use them?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging): _"The only time you should use tags in your title is when they are organic to the conversational tone of the title."_

Comment: Does UnityEngine.UI include any public objects that are in the namespace `UnityEngine.UI`? It's perfectly possible to create a project called `MyTestProject` and put everything inside it in the namespace `Sushi`. To access the project's contents, you would need `using Sushi;` not `using MyTestProject;`.

Comment: You should try reimporting everything or if this doesn't work try closing the project and deleting all the assembly and sc project files from your project's root folder and reopening the project.

Comment: Does the error message show up in Unity console, as well? Or does it only show up in VS?

Comment: Are you using Assembly Definitions in your project?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help, although I barely understood what any of you were saying. I found a thread that solved the problem though. Basically I had to backup my project's library folder, then delete the one in the project folder, then have unity regenerate the files, then delete it again and finally copy the original backup back into the project folder. That somehow solved the problem. Hope that can help someone else too!